# How to change google map from sateliteView to TrafficView

Tags: android

Is it possible to add optionsmenu to google map?

i.e changing the map from satelliteview to traffic view by selecting options menu?

Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Android-Google Maps Satellite toggle](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6529849/android-google-maps-satellite-toggle)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do by putting below code in Option Menu
Code:

```
mapView.setSatellite(false);
mapView.setTraffic(true);
```

To Create OptionMenu follow below steps:

Put code:

```
    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
        menu.add(0, 1, 0, "Satelite");
        menu.add(0, 2, 0, "Traffic");
                return true;
    }
```

and also put below code:

```
@Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
        switch (item.getItemId()) {
        case 1:
            mapView.setSatellite(true);
                        mapView.setTraffic(false); 
            return true;


        case 2:
                    mapView.setSatellite(false);
                    mapView.setTraffic(true); 
            return true;



        default:
            return false;
        }
    }
```

Hope it will help you.

Enjoy. :)

Comment: @Jeena: well i don't have try on it. Please you try manually and if it works then leave comment here that it works on it.

Answer (score 0):

The Options Menu has been deprecated in newer versions of Android. Take a look at the [Android Action Bar documentation](http://developer.android.com/design/patterns/actionbar.html). All you will need to do is set up an Action Bar with a button to toggle between satellite and traffic. The function calls for those are trivial.